# How allow user to select phone/facetime/email/iMessage in iPhone and iPad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

In iPhone and iPad when the user taps on a phone number or email address,how allow user to select phone/facetime/email/iMessage where appropriate.Plz help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i understood, You want to know about URL Schemes.

Please find reference on [Apple Docs...](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Introduction/Introduction.html)

More Links: [WIKI](http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes)

[Sample Project.](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk-working-with-url-schemes/)

Hope it works for you.

Comment: also can u please tell me which of the iphone/ipad versions support iMessage.?

Comment: or please tell me the os versions that support iMessage

Comment: iMessage is available for all iOS devices running on iOS 5.0 or later. But for MAC OS it is available for MAC OS Mountain Lion only.

Comment: Thank you.. :) Can you please also tell me which are the IOS versions that support Facetime.?